# Querying BigQuery based on where clause for dates

Tags: python-3.x, google-bigquery

I am trying to query the data from BigQuery based on where conditions where the data is extracted within specified input dates. I have tried the following two solutions, but neither of them are working for me.

```sql
SELECT Count(*)
FROM   `my-one-330114.results_out.results_validation_out` t
WHERE  date(parse_datetime('%d/%m/%Y', t.{col})) AS date_conv1 >= {end_time}
AND    date(parse_datetime('%d/%m/%Y', t.{col})) AS date_conv2 <= {start_time}
```

---

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   `my-one-330114.results_out.results_validation_out`
WHERE  parse({column} AS int64) <= format_date("%Y%m%d", parse({column} AS int64)) """ #AND CAST('%d/%m/%Y', DATE) <= CAST('%Y-%m-%d', '2021-11-01')
```

Comment: Try removing the aliases "date_conv1"

Comment: The error i got after removing them is the following:400 No matching signature for operator >= for argument types: DATE, INT64. Supported signature: ANY >= ANY at [1:82]

Comment: Are you sure that endtime and starttime parameter is date type.?

Comment: The start time and end time are from data type - datetime.date. I have created them with the following syntax:    start_time_time = datetime.datetime.today().date()
days = datetime.timedelta(delta)
end_time_time = datetime.datetime.today().date() - days                                                           However, the date column on big query is string.